# Click on a link in a table with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm facing come difficulties with a CasperJS script.
I would like to `click` on a link, the `edit` one.

```
<div class="list">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%">State</th>
                <th width="5%">State1</th>
                ....
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>                                 
                <tr class="myclass">
                    <td class="center"><a href="viewer.php?file=1902440_14313152"><img src="img/picto/picto.png"/></a></td>
                    ...
                    <td class="center actions">
                        <div class='relative'>
                                                                            <a href="#" class="info"><img src="img/info.png"/></a>
                                <a class="edit" href="viewer.php?file=19095CFBCD260702440_14313152"><img src="img/picto/picto.png"/></a>
```

I tried to use the `evaluate` function in the CasperJS API but it returns some [Object object] and it can't click on it.
Here is my code:

```
var link = casper.evaluate(function() {
    return [].map.call(__utils__.findAll('tr'), function(node) {
        return node.getAttribute('a');
    });
});
this.click(link);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, where's `link` defined?

Comment: `tr`s don't have an `a` attribute, right?

Comment: No they dont, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501494/click-on-a-link-in-a-table-with-casperjs#comment45325442_28501974

Comment: Please format your HTML before posting, poorly formatted HTML makes many people not even look at your question. Also, be more detailed with your question; nowhere did you specify that you wanted to click the 8th link with class within a `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

`casper.click()` expects a selector (CSS3 selectors, or XPath expressions through a helper utility). You can click a *single* element with

```
casper.click("tr.myclass .edit");
```

If you want to click a link in a specific row, you can use the `:nth-child()` selector:

```
casper.click("tr:nth-child(3) .edit"); // 3rd tr
```

Comment: You haven't actually made your point clear. Which *one* do you want to click? Or do you want to click all of them? If yes, in what way?

Comment: I want to click on one of the `tr`, no matters which one. But the link is in the 8th `td`, this is where the `edit` link is and where i want to click

Comment: So? Are there `.edit` elements in the other `td`s? That this is an issue?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I think the OP means `casper.click("tr .edit:nth-child(8)")`

Comment: @JuanMendes If anything the OP means `casper.click("tr + tr td:nth-child(8) .edit")`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Truth is the OP is not being very clear, but your answer and the comments should have enough information for them to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, that helped me a lot, but i'm still stuck with that. If i try your selector in the page with Jquery it works `$("tr:nth-child(3) .edit").click();` but after the `casper.click` with the same selector i'm still on the same page ( i tested it with the `assertTitle`)...

Comment: @angezanetti It should work, maybe there are errors. Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events.

Comment: Page.error returns this: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file:///usr/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Comment: @angezanetti This error would have been probably there before you even registered to the `page.error` event. Does it come after the script execution finished? If yes, then this has nothing to do with your problem. If yes, then there is something fishy and you didn't provide enough information (are you running this on a local html file?).

Comment: @ArtjomB. This seems to be a known issue with phantomJS 1.9.8 https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/1068. I try to use the 2.0

Comment: @angezanetti You say that it works with `jQuery.click()`? jQuery uses synthetic mouse events whereas CasperJS tries to use the native PhantomJS mouse events. The difference may be that the element is occluded by some other element and therefore PhantomJS click doesn't work.

Comment: @ArtjomB.You mean i should use a more 'top-level' selector ?

Comment: @angezanetti No, I don't mean that. I don't know what you can try. It is a [guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) at this point.